# Distinguish between page navigation and fast app switch on WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, fast-app-switching

To dispose and re-create resources, I have to distinguish between navigation to another page of the application and a fast app switch.

How could I accomplish this? Which events do I have to use to do this task correctly?

The application is a XAML with DirectX app running on Windows Phone 8.

With best regards,
Emi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register for OnNavigated events in the application frame (`PhoneApplicationFrame` or any custom frame you use), or override the `OnNavigatedFrom` method of your page.

Then you can query the `NavigationEventArgs` to check if the URI is an external page. For example:

```
    private void OnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs navigationEventArgs)
    {
        if (navigationEventArgs.Uri.ToString() == "app://external/")
        {
            // This is a Fast App Switch navigation

        }
    }
```